# Read XLSX file without specifying column and rows with XLSX pkg in Julia

Tags: julia, xlsx

I have an excel file (.xlsx) that I want to read with XLSX.jl pkg. If I use `xf = XLSX.readxlsx("filename.xlsx")` I get the following.

```
XLSXFile("filename.xlsx") containing 1 Worksheet
        sheetname size          range        
-------------------------------------------------
           Sheet1 size unknown
```

If I instead use `XLSX.readdata("filename.xlsx", "Sheet1", "A1:J57")` I get a `57x10 matrix` with all the data in the excel file.

I have tried `XLSX.readdata(), XLSX.openxlsx(), XLSX.readtable(), XLSX.readxlsx()`
But the only that works is `readdata`and if I specify `"A1:J57` Is there a way so I don't need to specify column and rows? I have no control over the format of the sheet in the excelfile.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `XLSX.get_dimension` as in the example below:

```
julia> xf = XLSX.readxlsx(raw"c:\temp\Book1.xlsx")
XLSXFile("Book1.xlsx") containing 1 Worksheet
            sheetname size          range
-------------------------------------------------
               Sheet1 16x4          A1:D16

julia> worksheet = xf[XLSX.sheetnames(xf)[1]]
16×4 XLSX.Worksheet: ["Sheet1"](A1:D16)

julia> XLSX.get_dimension(worksheet)
A1:D16
```

Comment: My problem is that when I use ```XLSX.readxlsx()``` I get no size or range of the worksheet. It is just empty, but the excel file isn't empty.

Comment: what `XLSX.get_dimension(worksheet)` is returning? You could also try `XLSX.getdata(worksheet)`

Comment: ```XLSX.get_dimension(worksheet)``` returns nothing. ```XLSX.getdata(worksheet)``` returns  ```ERROR: Worksheet dimension is unkown.```